# UbuntuGIS packages on ppa.launchpad

Tags: pgrouting, installation, ubuntugis

I am trying to install pgrouting on ubuntu 14.04 like this:

## Add pgRouting launchpad repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:georepublic/pgrouting
sudo apt-get update
```

## Install pgRouting package (for Ubuntu 14.04)

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting
```

But  "apt-get update" fails with:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Where did you find those instructions? Have you tried these http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt

Comment: This has nothing to do with the pgRouting PPA. As the error message says, the UbuntuGIS PPA can't be fetched.

Comment: The instructions can be found here: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html#pgrouting. Maybe badly updated to Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

UbuntuGis was never updated for 14.04. If you look in [ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/), the last entry is for Saucy, not Trusty. Hence your failures.

Comment: Current development of ubuntugis can be found in the ubuntugis unstable ppa, but they only have postgis, not postgresql-pgrouting.

Answer (score 0):

The pgrouting package can be found here:

https://launchpad.net/~georepublic/+archive/ubuntu/pgrouting?field.series_filter=trusty

So it is just the first line of your commands that is not working.

To get Postgresql 9.3, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/546266/how-to-install-postgresql-9-3-instead-of-default-9-4-in-ubuntu-14-10